# Solr Cloud Security not working for internal authentication

Tags: java, solr, jvm, solrj

I am trying to use Solr Security on Solr 5.0 Cloud. Following process I have used :-
1. Modifying web.xml :-

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>AdminAllowedQueries</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>admin</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>  </security-constraint>     
<login-config>
 <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 <realm-name>Solr Realm</realm-name></login-config>

 <security-role>
 <description>Admin</description>
 <role-name>admin</role-name>   </security-role>
```

2. Changes in jetty.xml :-

   `<Call name="addBean">
     <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
         <Set name="name">Solr Realm</Set>
         <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
         <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </Call>`
3. Creating realm.properties:- `solradmin: solradmin,admin`
4. Set SOLR OPTS in solr.in.sh:-

   SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -DinternalAuthCredentialsBasicAuthUsername=solradmin"
   SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -DinternalAuthCredentialsBasicAuthPassword=solradmin"

I am getting Unauthorized error while creating collection using following command:-

```
localhost:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=test&collection.configName=testconf&numShards=1
```

Kindly help or suggest the best to get this done.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I had a cloud running fine, but when I added basic authentication, as you outlined above, I could only get one Solr node running in the cluster -- the other one stays at "Recovering" permanently.

Comment: I am running into the same problems. Did you guys find a solution for this?

Comment: didn't find any relevant answer, so currently I am not using authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the basic auth password and username to the url like this?:

http://solradmin:solradmin@localhost:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=test&collection.configName=testconf&numShards=1